# python-fabric-manually set host parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I want to insert my env.host manually.I have file having list of diff env.host.something like this:

My host.py:

```
 @task
 def v2bg():
 env.hosts = ["12.12.11.132","13.10.18.22"]

 @task
 def api():
 env.hosts = ["4.3.81.27:2201", "4.3.1.7:2202", "20.3.18.07:2203", "60.83.581.27:2204"]

 @task
 def emailapi():
env.hosts = ["30.40.50.56:2201", "40.40.36.56:2202"]

 @task
 def v2emailapi():
 env.hosts = ["20.18.148.30:2201", "20.18.48.3:2202"]
```

My emailapi.py

```
import host
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import *
from fabric.contrib import *

env.user = "ubuntu"
env.key_filename = "~/Documents/Pem/sec"
env.parallel = True
env.warn_only = True
```

I want my emailapi.py manually pick up these Ip by importing host.py file.
How can i do that i am still in confuse??Please help me out.

```
  "networks": {
    "v4": [
     {
       "ip_address": "104.131.186.241",
       "netmask": "255.255.240.0",
       "gateway": "104.131.176.1",
       "type": "public"
     }
   ],
```

I more thing, if i want to retrieve my ip_address and set automatically env.host how can i acheive it.

Comment: I read this 3 times and i still dont understand what you're asking, please rephrase... everything.

Comment: sorry,I want to store my ip_address field in any variable.And this variable automatically pick ip in env.host.  Suppose I have 5 diff Ip and I have 5 diff vm I want to perform diff work for diff Ip & want automatically pick up diff env.host diff Ip and perform there respecting task.

Comment: Ok i think you're getting bogged down with the code, what are you trying to accomplish with the script. Explain it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this. Let me know if it works.

my_roles.json

`{
    "ip": [ "user@someip.example.com", "user@someip.example.com" ],
    "ip1": [ "user@someip.example.com", "user@someip.example.com" ]
}`

fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import env, run, task
import json

def load_roles():
    with open('my_roles.json') as f:
        env.roledefs = json.load(f)

load_roles()

@task
def my_task():
    run("hostname")
```

CLI

`fab -R ip my_task`

output from running "my_task" for each of web1 and web2 is here